# Detecting anchors with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, url, anchor

I want to know if it's possible to have the script detect the URL anchor, and load content specific to that anchor. For instance, I have this line of code:

`<a href="#home"><span id="homeMenu">Home</span></a>`

This line of code listens to this code:

```
$("#homeMenu").click(function () {
    $("#home_content").show("slow");
    $("#accommodations_content").hide("slow");
    });
```

How could I make it that if the user visits `http://www.myurl.com/home.html#home` that it loads the home content automatically. This should also work for all other anchors that I would want to implement.

I want this because, right now, if the user visits any of the anchors directly, no mater which anchor, it will always display the home page. So, is there a way to detect which URL is loaded and then run a script on that?

**EDIT**

So,currently it ONLY loads accommodations (even when on the #Home)

Current code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {
            document.getElementById("javascriptCheck").style.visibility = 'hidden';
            $("#menu").load("snippets/menu.html");
            $("#locationMenu").load("snippets/locationMenu.html");
            $("#home_content").load("snippets/home_content.html");
            $("#accommodations_content").load("snippets/accommodations.html");
            $("#history").load("snippets/history.html");
            $("#footer").load("snippets/footer.html");

            var hash = window.location.hash;
            if (hash = "#Home") {
                $("#home_content").show("slow");
                $("#accommodations_content").hide("slow");
            }
            if (hash = "#Accommodations") {
                $("#accommodations_content").show("slow");
                $("#home_content").hide("slow");     
            }
            } );
        </script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to check for hash tags on page load.

use this code:

```
var identifier = window.location.hash; //gets everything after the hashtag i.e. #home

if (identifier === "#home") {
     $("#home_content").show("slow");
     $("#accommodations_content").hide("slow");
}
```

Comment: For some reason I'm having issues with this code. Where exactly should it go?

Comment: Ok, that's why I did, it doesn't load right. I posted my code and the issue above.

Comment: Ok, I found out what was broken about the code, and I feel like a huge idiot. `if (identifier = "#home")` should be `if (identifier == "#home")`

Answer (score 5):

I guess, you want something like this: [jQuery hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/). It allows you to react to changes to the hash and load for example other content via AJAX - but you can do other stuff as well. The user even can use the back & forward button of the browser to go to a previous state.